# Modifying ini files using shell script

Tags: shell, ini

I have an `ini` file similar to this

```
[test]
foo=bar
```

and if we call this `ini` file as `test1.ini`

How do I change the value of `foo` to `foobarbaz` for example using `shell script`.

I have tried the following and it doesn't work for me. I don't see the updated changes in the ini file. how do I write it?

```
sed "/^foo=/s/=.*/=foobarbaz/" < test1.ini
```

Do you have any other suggestions

Comment: Assuming you mean you want `foo=foobarbaz` and not `foobarbaz=bar`, your code worked for me under Windows, mingw (MSYS), bash.  Quoting is shell-dependent; try using single quotes (`'`) around the `sed` string rather than double-quotes (`"`).

Comment: Use the `-i` option.  `sed -i "/^foo=/s/=.*/=foobarbaz/" test1.ini` (note that the redirection `<` has been removed from the command).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have the file updated, use the `-i` option of sed:

```
sed -i "/^foo=/s/=.*/=foobarbaz/" test1.ini
```

From `man sed`:

> -**i[SUFFIX]**, --**in-place[=SUFFIX]**
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)

So you can also do

```
sed -i.bak "/^foo=/s/=.*/=foobarbaz/" test1.ini
```

Answer (score 11):

I personally use a more elaborated `sed` command, as the same option might appear in several different sections:

```
sh$ sed -i.bak '/^\[test]/,/^\[/{s/^foo[[:space:]]*=.*/foo = foobarbaz/}' test1.ini
#       ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#    make a       in the right         perform the substitution
#   *backup*       section                as you want
```

And as a safety net, I would add:

```
sh$ diff test1.ini{,.bak}
2c2
< foo = foobarbaz
---
> foo=bar
```

Answer (score 4):

## Crudini

Crudini is a command line interface to .ini files.

### Solution

```
crudini --set test1.ini test foo foobarbaz
```

Or, more generally,

`crudini` --set   *FILENAME.INI*   *SECTION*   *PARAMETER*   *VALUE*

### Details

Written in 2013 by [Pádraig Brady](https://www.pixelbeat.org/), crudini has become a standard solution in the UNIX toolkit in the years since this question was first asked. Many GNU/Linux distributions prepackage crudini as part of the OS, making installation simple (e.g., `apt install crudini`). It also works on Apple MacOS and Microsoft Windows.

I have used my own custom `sed` scripts in the past, but crudini is easier, more powerful, and less likely to accidentally destroy my files.

See the [crudini homepage](https://github.com/pixelb/crudini) for more details.

### Dangers

While crudini is safer than `sed` for most people, it is not perfect.

- Crudini does not have sed's `-i~` option to automatically create a backup file when operating in-place.
- It is way too easy to delete an entire section.
- `crudini --set config.ini foo x=3` will blithely create a line that says, `x=3 =` .
  *[Reportedly this is fixed in the latest release.]*
- Its handling of lists (comma separated values) is naive.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @hackerb9. The third "x=3" issue above is addressed in latest git. Re backups, I was thinking that using external tools like cp to manage backups is more flexible, and more in the unix mode of do one thing well

Comment: Thanks, @pixelbeat. By editing in-place, crudini is already doing two things. It would be more flexible if `crudini` honored sed's `-i[SUFFIX]`, `--in-place=[SUFFIX]` option. That way a person could use `cp` if they like or request a backup with a specific suffix.

Comment: By the way, the traditional Unix folks don't use cp before using a filter on a file, they do this: `mv foo foo~; sed 's/fred/juki/' foo~ > foo`. That keeps the original file's inode unchanged and reads the file only once. It may make sense for Crudini to support that mode by only doing in-place editing by default when stdout is a tty (the screen).