# How to replace the value of a variable in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

In a shell script file, suppose there is one line like this.

```
IP_address=192.168.1.12
```

From command line, how to change it to?

```
IP_address=192.168.1.16
```

I think it may not be done by "sed" because the search string to be replaced is not constant. Maybe "awk"? But I am not expert on that. Thanks a lot for the hint.

To be more specific, the search pattern in the file is "x=y" and should be replaced with "x=z", using only command line tools.

Extra, just to clear some trivials

"y" is not fixed, only "x".

In plain English: I want to search the definition of variable "x" in a script and change the value it is defined to a new value. I don't care (or don't know) what the old value of "x" is, I just want to change it to a new value.

Comment: If you're not sure of _what is it that you want to achieve_, how do you expect an answer?

Comment: just to be obnoxious `sed 's/12/16/' <<< "IP_address=192.168.1.12"`

Comment: `sed 's/\(IP_address=\).*/\1192.168.1.16/' filename`??

Comment: @devnull, Great, works! Thank you.

Comment: @tripleee, No, it is not duplicate. I use "IP address" only as an illustrative example. My question is more general, and the answers in other question are not applicable in my case.

Comment: There are also many questions where the value can be anything at all; if that isn't suitable either, please tell us more about your conditions.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567275/modifying-ini-files-using-shell-script

Answer (score 2):

Sed will work just fine:

```
$ sed -e "/^$Y=/s/=.*/=$X/" $script > $script.new
```

The pattern `/<search>/s/<old>/<new>/` means:

- Find all occurrences of `<search>` (which will be lines beginning with `$Y=`).
- Replace on the line the equal sign and everything after it.
- Replace it with `=$X`.

Note that this entire script is in double quotes, so that the shell can interpolate `$X` and `$Y`.

Answer (score 0):

With awk, this is as generic as possible:

```
awk -F= -v OFS="=" -v x="IP Address" -v y="192.168.1.16" '
    $1 == x {$2 = y} 1
' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```